# Baked normals not appearing correct in EEVEE, but is correct in Cycles, why?

Tags: baking, normal-map

I am trying to bake a relatively simple high-poly mesh onto a low poly version of that mesh. After some trial and error I got okay results when looking through viewport shading mode on Cycles
[image: the results of the render and view through viewport shading]

but when looking at it through Lookdev mode, which I need to texture paint it, i see this result on the right

[image]

When i look at my normal map, it makes sense why it is showing this way because it's all over the place, but for some reason even though i had since unwrapped it differently and gotten the better result on the left, it still shows like this in the *UV Editor*.

[image]

but as you can see here, this is how it is actually unwrapped and baked, as seen in the cycles render and viewport shader
[image]

Why do my normal map looks fine in Cycles and viewpoert shader, as if it baked the way I unwrapped it, yet when looking at EEVEE it looks all messed up as it is appearing in the uv editor? The one that's applied is giving me the good result, it makes no sense. I'm a beginner by the way.

Comment: Sounds like you've got it sorted out.  But a couple notes: you didn't pack the normal map, so we have to rebake.  Check out file->external data->pack all into .blend.  Also, if you save a file, there's a sidebar with options like "compress file".  If you enable that, there won't be any space saving from also putting it into a .zip-- it compresses using zip compression.  Finally, now that it's done, my normal bake (using your settings) looks nothing like your normal map.  I suspect you didn't save the bake and it reverted to a previous version of the image.  Bake extrusion is way too high btw.

Answer (score 0):

i think it is because my transforms weren't applied on both meshes, possibly, i did that and it worked out.